# Listview Command Set on SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx, error, 2019, spfx-extensions

Has anyone succeeded in building a Listview Command Set on SharePoint 2019?
I am using SPFx 1.4.1 as recommended.

**Problem**: the custom buttons in the ribbon disappear after opening a different page (e.g. edit one of the views) and the `console.log` is flooded with uncaught errors.

For example:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error
> at t [as constructor] (listview-host-assembly.js?uniqueId=2g4QD:92:15766)
> at new t (listview-host-assembly.js?uniqueId=2g4QD:449:22174)
> at e.buildErrorWithVerboseLog (listview-host-assembly.js?uniqueId=2g4QD:449:14408)
> at e.buildLoadPathDependencyError (listview-host-assembly.js?uniqueId=2g4QD:449:12154)
> at listview-host-assembly.js?uniqueId=2g4QD:449:63944
> at listview-host-assembly.js?uniqueId=2g4QD:449:64316

Thanks in advance.